# Actually I am not able to access the token with this code, It says validation error, Where is the problem or How can I do It

Tags: reactjs

This is the code that I am getting errors
help me to get the access token through this email id and password.
let me know how the code has to be

```
useEffect(()=>{
           axios.post('https://stage.api.sloovi.com/login',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email : 'smithcheryl@yahoo.com',
              password : '12345678'
      
            })
          })
           .then(res=>console.log(res))
        },[])
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax for axios post needs update. Please check the output

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post("https://stage.api.sloovi.com/login", {
        email: "smithcheryl@yahoo.com",
        password: "12345678"
      })
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data.results.token));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Edit to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This can be tested in https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-axios-post-z48k7

Comment: To get the exact token,   update the line to:   console.log(res.data.results.token)

Comment: then why we are using header and method, I saw some of youtube videos they are using header and method.

Comment: it may be required in some special cases . but most things work out of box. Please add your answer as required.

Comment: an example with similar syntax : axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});

Answer (score -2):

The main response data comes under `res.data` in the case of axios, can you try it once?

Sidenote: Please add a

```
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

to check if you are getting some error or not.